# Is there a way to use the lead function to figure out the first row that meets a condition?

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi I have a dataframe as such,

```
df= structure(list(a = c(1, 3, 4, 6, 3, 2, 5, 1), b = c(1, 3, 4, 
                                                    2, 6, 7, 2, 6), c = c(6, 3, 6, 5, 3, 6, 5, 3), d = c(6, 2, 4, 
                                                                                                         5, 3, 7, 2, 6), e = c(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 3), f = c(2, 3, 4, 
                                                                                                                                                              2, 2, 7, 5, 2)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       8L), class = "data.frame")
df$total = apply ( df, 1,sum )
df$row = seq ( 1, nrow ( df ))
```

so the dataframe looks like this.

```
    > df
  a b c d e f total row
1 1 1 6 6 1 2    17   1
2 3 3 3 2 2 3    16   2
3 4 4 6 4 4 4    26   3
4 6 2 5 5 5 2    25   4
5 3 6 3 3 6 2    23   5
6 2 7 6 7 7 7    36   6
7 5 2 5 2 6 5    25   7
8 1 6 3 6 3 2    21   8
```

what I want to do is figure the first leading row where the total is greater than the current. For example for row 1 the total is 17 and the nearest leading row >= 17 would be row 3.

I could loop through each row but it gets really messy. Is this possible?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need to create a column?  `df %>% mutate(new = which(total >= 17)[2])`

Comment: Or perhaps, `df %>% mutate(ind = na_if(row * (lead(total) >= total), 0) + 1 )` if you want to do this on each row

Comment: @akrun hey thanks for that, however I think the 2nd example is giving some errors. For example for row 3 the total is 26 and the next leading row >=26 is row 6 but is giving NA instead.

Comment: I get 6 instead i.e. `df %>% mutate(ind = na_if(row * (lead(total) >= total), 0) + 1 ) %>% pull(ind)
[1] NA  3 NA NA  6 NA NA NA`. I have to insert `NA` to make the lengths correct for that new column.  If you need a `vector` of values, instead of `mutate` you can use `summarise` which is more flexible i.e. `df %>% summarise(ind = na.omit(na_if(row * (lead(total) >= total), 0) + 1 )) %>% pull(ind)
[1] 3 6`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this in 2 steps with dplyr. First we set grouping to `rowwise`, which applies the operation on each row (basically it makes it work like we were doing an apply loop through the rows), then we find all the rows where `total` is larger than that row's `total`. Then we drop those that come before the current row and pick the first (which is the next one):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(nxt = list(which(.$total > total)),
           nxt = nxt[nxt > row][1])

# A tibble: 8 × 9
# Rowwise: 
      a     b     c     d     e     f total   row   nxt
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
1     1     1     6     6     1     2    17     1     3
2     3     3     3     2     2     3    16     2     3
3     4     4     6     4     4     4    26     3     6
4     6     2     5     5     5     2    25     4     6
5     3     6     3     3     6     2    23     5     6
6     2     7     6     7     7     7    36     6    NA
7     5     2     5     2     6     5    25     7    NA
8     1     6     3     6     3     2    21     8    NA
```

Comment: this is great thank you; the last part is super clever I was wondering how to only search forward.